How can I handle responsiveness in a server component without css?
This is basically the root of the page. And it has 3 components, the MainMap (Client) the ListCasas(Server).
The button at the end changes the url searchParams and updates the UI. Now, this code runs as expected (UI wise) but in the console there are a ton of errors, due to it being a client component, as ListCasas was supposed to be Server.
I think this might also be causing page reloads. But it seems that the error fundamentally comes down to the useMediaQuery(). It requires a client component to not throw a error (useEffect, useState) And so I can't figure out a way to be able to keep this a server component, but also know the window size?
code for mapClientComponent.tsx
'use client';

import MainMap from '@/app/[lang]/components/main-map';
import ListCasas from '../../ui/list-casas';
import NavBar from '../components/nav';
import { Locale } from '@/i18next.config';
import { getDictionary } from '@/app/lib/dictionary';
import { getImoveis } from '@/app/lib/data';
import { Suspense, useState } from 'react';
import FiltersBar from './bar';
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import useMediaQuery from '@/hooks/mediaQuery';
// import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
// const useMediaQuery = dynamic(() => import('@/hooks/mediaQuery'), {
//   ssr: false,
// });

export default function MapClientComponent({
  params,
  searchParams,
  mapData,
  page,
}: {
  params: { lang: Locale };
  mapData: any;
  page: any;
  searchParams?: {
    //   query?: string;
    lat?: string;
    lng?: string;
    zona?: string;
    page?: string;
    sorting?: string;
    types?: string;
    min_price?: string;
    max_price?: string;
    number_of_rooms?: string;
    exact_matches?: string;
    yt?: string;
    vr?: string;
    beach?: string;
    pool?: string;
    isMapVisible?: string;
  };
}) {
  const lg = useMediaQuery(1024);
  const isVis = searchParams?.isMapVisible || 'false';
  const isMapVisible = isVis === 'true'; // Convert to boolean

  const mapShouldShow = lg ? isMapVisible : true;
  const listShouldShow = lg ? !isMapVisible : true;

  // console.log('lg', lg);
  // console.log(isMapVisible, 'isvisible');
  // console.log(mapShouldShow, 'mapShouldShow');
  // console.log(listShouldShow, 'listShouldShow');

  //logic for visibility button
  const searchParamss = useSearchParams();
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const { replace } = useRouter();
  const paramss = new URLSearchParams(searchParamss);
  function handleVis() {
    const newIsMapVisible =
      searchParams?.isMapVisible === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';

    paramss.set('isMapVisible', newIsMapVisible.toString());

    replace(`${pathName}?${paramss.toString()}`);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex h-[100vh] min-w-full pt-[120px]">
      {mapShouldShow && (
        <Suspense
          key={isMapVisible.toString() + lg.toString()}
          fallback={'map loading...'}
        >
          <MainMap
            isMapVisible={isMapVisible}
            houses={mapData.houses}
            dictionary={page}
            lang={params.lang}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: searchParams?.lat, lng: searchParams?.lng }}
          />
        </Suspense>
      )}
      {listShouldShow && (
        <Suspense key={'listCasas'} fallback={'List loading...'}>
          <ListCasas
            params={{ lang: params.lang }}
            searchParams={{
              sorting: searchParams?.sorting,
              page: searchParams?.page,
              zona: searchParams?.zona,
              tipos: searchParams?.types,
              min_price: searchParams?.min_price,
              max_price: searchParams?.max_price,
              number_of_rooms: searchParams?.number_of_rooms,
              exact_matches: searchParams?.exact_matches,
              yt: searchParams?.yt,
              vr: searchParams?.vr,
              beach: searchParams?.beach,
              pool: searchParams?.pool,
            }}
          />
        </Suspense>
      )}

      <button
        className="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-6 flex justify-center text-center text-white"
        onClick={() => handleVis()}
      >
        <div className="w-[150px] bg-black p-2">
          {searchParams?.isMapVisible === 'true' ? 'Show List' : 'Show Map'}
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

code for mediaQuery.ts:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const useMediaQuery = (width: number) => {
  const [targetReached, setTargetReached] = useState(false);

  const updateTarget = (e: MediaQueryListEvent) => {
    setTargetReached(e.matches);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const media = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${width}px)`);
    media.addEventListener('change', updateTarget);

    // Check on mount (callback is not called until a change occurs)
    if (media.matches) {
      setTargetReached(true);
    }

    return () => media.removeEventListener('change', updateTarget);
  }, [width]);

  return targetReached;
};

export default useMediaQuery;

UI working as expected, but console throws errors:
CasaCard is a child to ListCasas...
app-index.js:33 Warning: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server. at ListCasas
app-index.js:33 Warning: A component was suspended by an uncached promise. Creating promises inside a Client Component or hook is not yet supported, except via a Suspense-compatible library or framework. at ListCasas
Warning: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server. at CasaCard
app-index.js:33 Warning: A component was suspended by an uncached promise. Creating promises inside a Client Component or hook is not yet supported, except via a Suspense-compatible library or framework. at CasaCard
Are these errors going to be an issue with SSR? Or lead to some sort of unexpected error? Im not sure how the UI even is able to load with hydration errors?
I would just really love to be able to remove the 'use client'. And with css it would be extremely easy, but since in this case the map takes a lot of resources, I don't think css is a a viable solution...

The error seems pretty clear (if idiotic in 2024 because it claims basic JS isn't supported in this supposedly modern framework): "async/await is not yet supported in Client Components". So either stop using async/await/promises, or stop using "use client"? And frankly, I'd go with the latter, because it sure sounds like that unofficial pragma "breaks" how javascript is supposed to work.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'd love to remove use client, but then I wouldn't be able to call the useMediaQuery() which I need to make the page responsive. This must be possible somehow, because looking at https://www.zillow.com/homes you can see that the design is responsive, and I really doubt the entire page would be a 'use client' just to enable this responsiveness. Might be wrong tho.

I don't think the error is saying you cannot use async/await at all in client components, but rather saying that you cannot you cannot use aysnc components as client components (a newer next.js feature). I'm curious what ListCasas and CasaCard look like since the error references them. Are they async components without the use server directive perhaps?

Responsiveness must take place on the client though, unless I'm way off base somehow. You can't run code accounting for the screen size from the server which knows nothing about it

@BrianThompson yes they are async components without use server. I understand that it should happen on the client, but for that I would need to wrap the entire page in a client component? And it would mean every page would have to be loaded on the client?
I just find it hard to believe that Zillow would sacrifice SSR for responsiveness, unless they could actually keep the page on the server and without any directive.

As a first step I would try just adding the use server to them. I am fairly new to Next.js' async components but I believe you are allowed to render server components from client components and the framework will SSR the async ones and send them to the client?

I'm confused by the references to zillow. A quick look at React Dev Tools on their site is showing they're using React 16.14, which doesn't even support async components, making the comparison mostly irrelevant

@BrianThompson hmm interesting, I said they were using it because if you search for next in the elements you can find  tags like this:

Which leads me to believe they are indeed using it? But still even if they are not, can't their method be replicated? Once the window reaches a certain breakpoint, it would update the searchParams ?isMapVisible=true&isListVisible=true, and then it could be responsive, and still stay on the server?

I am just completely lost as to how, or even if it's possible to call that client side function on the MapClientComponent (now would be MapServerComp), which is where I need to have the visibility logic.

I found an alternative, instead of calling the useMediaQuery() in the main page, and forcing it to be a Client component.
I was able to move the logic to the changeVisibility button, which is already Client. Annd there, have an useEffect() which on page load, will redirect to the current page, + the searchParams isMapVisible and isListVisible.
This method works and gives no errors, but would like to hear any thoughts as to if this is a nice approach.
changeVisButton:
'use client';

import useMediaQuery from '@/hooks/mediaQuery';
import { ListBulletIcon, MapIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ChangeVisButton(searchParams: {
  isMapVisible?: string;
  isListVisibile?: string;
}) {
  const searchParamss = useSearchParams();
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const { replace } = useRouter();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParamss);

  const lg = useMediaQuery(1024);
  console.log('lg', lg);

  function handleVis() {
    const newIsMapVisible =
      searchParams.isMapVisible === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
    const newIsListVisible =
      searchParams.isListVisibile === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';

    //Only does anything if screen size is SM, the button wont even show in LG
    if (lg) {
      params.set('isMapVisible', newIsMapVisible.toString());
      params.set('isListVisible', newIsListVisible.toString());
    }

    replace(`${pathName}?${params.toString()}`);
  }

  // console.log(params.get('isMapVisible'), 'ismapvisible');

  //If lg changes, alter the searchParams. Show both on lg screens, and only 1 in sm screens...
  //This will load on page load too to set the correct visibility, and pass it to params...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!lg) {
      params.set('isMapVisible', 'true');
      params.set('isListVisible', 'true');
    } else if (lg && params.get('isMapVisible') === 'true') {
      //TODO: In here, we should be setting the isMapVisible to false. So that the list is the default
      //Its only if the user comes from LG to SM, that this triggers, NOT on-load
      //But for some reason, setting isMap to false, will cause the onLoad to malfunction
      params.set('isListVisible', 'false');
    } else {
      params.set('isMapVisible', 'false');
      params.set('isListVisible', 'true');
    }
    replace(`${pathName}?${params.toString()}`);
  }, [lg, params]);

  return (
    <button
      className="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-6 flex justify-center text-center text-white lg:hidden"
      onClick={() => handleVis()}
    >
      <div className="flex w-[145px] items-center justify-evenly rounded-lg bg-white p-2 text-black hover:bg-gray-200">
        {searchParams.isMapVisible === 'true' ? (
          <ListBulletIcon className="h-[22px] w-[22px]" />
        ) : (
          <MapIcon className="h-[22px] w-[22px]" />
        )}
        {searchParams.isMapVisible === 'true' ? 'Show List' : 'Show Map'}
      </div>
    </button>
  );
}

and then control the visibility on the Server component with:
{searchParams?.isMapVisible === 'true' && (

and
{searchParams?.isListVisible === 'true' && (

